# How to get next day date in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

In my module I have some validation check i.e, I get some date format from server from that I need to get next day date value and do rest of the things but for several attempts, I couldn't find proper solution

**Here my code:**

```
NSDate *date1 = [_simpleDateformatter dateFromString:value];
_startDate = [_simpleDateformatter dateFromString:startDateStr];

NSLog(@"nextDate - %@ ",[date1 initWithTimeInterval:(24*60*60) sinceDate:_startDate])  ;
NSLog(@"earlierdate - %@ ",[date1 earlierDate:_startDate])  ;
NSLog(@"laterDate - %@ ",[date1 laterDate:_startDate])  ;
```

Date format is : **[_simpleDateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];**

My output :

```
nextDate - 2017-06-01 18:30:00 +0000 
earlierdate - 2014-07-23 18:30:00 +0000 
laterDate - 2017-05-31 18:30:00 +0000
```

Expected output :

```
2014-07-25 18:30:00 +0000
```

Comment: You need the next date of specific day or only tomorrow?

Comment: Can you give me a value of startDateStr ? In my project code is working properly.

Comment: **Do not use 86400 for date math**

Comment: @ReinierMelian next day of specific day

Comment: @NilayShah  startDateStr =  @"20170601"